# Getting an error using Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am getting this error while overwriting the `contains()` method.

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasPreviouslyLinkedCommand') in cypress

Here is the `commands.js` file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("clickOnLinks", (linkText) => {
  cy.get("a").contains(linkText).click();
});

// overwriting contains()
// passing the same parameter for the contains method

Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery(
  "contains",
  (originalFn, subject, filter, text, options = {}) => {
    // determine if the filter argument was passed

    if (typeof text === "object") {
      options = text;
      text = filter;
      filter = undefined;
    }
    options.matchCase = false;

    return originalFn(subject, filter, text, options);
  }
);
```

And this is my test file:

```
describe("Custom command", () => {
  it("overwriting the custom commands", () => {
    cy.visit("https://magento.softwaretestingboard.com/");

    // calling clickOnLinks command to click on the links
    cy.clickOnLinks("RADIANT TEE").should("exist");
    // verifying after performing click action

    cy.get("span[class='base']").should("have.text", "Radiant Tee");
  });
});
```

I'm using the latest version of cypress - 12.7.0

I have tried using this one as well but no luck -
`Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery`

What am I missing? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is the `this` binding of `originalFn` not being set, can be fixed with `originalFn.bind(this)`.

I took the parameter naming and resolution from the source, and defaulted the options (aka userOptions) to `{}` in case they are not passed.

There is a weird thing - the `prevSubject` is no longer present. That might have happened when `contains` changed from a command to a query, but haven't figured out how it get's the prevSubject(s) yet.

In any case, this is passing with `cy.get('a').contains('RADIANT TEE')`.

I haven't tested other variations yet.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery(
  "contains",
  function (contains, filter, text, userOptions = {}) {

    // This is parameter resolution from Cypress v12.7.0 source
    if (Cypress._.isRegExp(text)) {
      // .contains(filter, text)
      // Do nothing
    } else if (Cypress._.isObject(text)) {
      // .contains(text, userOptions)
      userOptions = text
      text = filter
      filter = ''
    } else if (Cypress._.isUndefined(text)) {
      // .contains(text)
      text = filter
      filter = ''
    }

    userOptions.matchCase = false;

    let contains0 = contains.bind(this)    // this line fixes the error

    return contains0(filter, text, userOptions)
  }
)
```

Comment: hey I posted you answer on the corresponding Github Issue (with credit), I hope that's ok for you https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6564#issuecomment-1914085609

Comment: I think the issue **cy.contains() should be case-insensitive by default #6564** was raised before `overwiteQuery` was introduced. Now, the documentation on [Custom Queries](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-queries#Usage) mentions this fix (see blue box).

Comment: made that also clearer, thanks for the info!